# Add stopwords resource for NLTK in conda environment

Tags: python, nltk, conda

I'm trying to create a `conda` environment that includes `NLTK`. In my `conda_requirements.yaml` file under the `pip` section I list `NLTK` with `- nltk==3.2.5`. When running a script with the import line `from nltk.corpus import stopwords` I get the following

```
LookupError: 
**********************************************************************
  Resource stopwords not found.
  Please use the NLTK Downloader to obtain the resource:

  >>> import nltk
  >>> nltk.download('stopwords')

  Searched in:
    - 'various/directories'
**********************************************************************
```

Without having to manually open up a python shell and run the suggested commands, how can I set up a `conda` environment to install the `stopwords` resource upon environment creation?

Comment: Are you using shell scripting on top of that?

Comment: Why not just use `conda` to install NLTK?  The package is available from the `conda-forge` channel